# kendoui grid with dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dynamic-columns

i'm trying to generare a grid with dynamic columns

in order to achieve this i've made some asp.net service that generate: columns, model and data (in json format).
These methods are called by ajax (not in async way, to get the data immediatlely)

the grid doesn't seem show the columns (provided dynamically from "Search.Grid.GenerateColumns") but shows columns according to the data/model
A further proof of this behaviour is that if i add a format = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" to a date column (in the columns collection) the date in the grid is not formatted

```
Search.Grid.Init = function ()
{
    var _rootUrl = "http://.................."

    //====================build the datasource==================
    var mainGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: _rootUrl + 'Repository.aspx/GetArchiveData',   
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation === "read" ) {
                    return JSON.stringify({ archivio: Search.SelectedArchive.Value });
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "d.data",
            total: "d.total",
            model: Search.Grid.GenerateModel(Search.SelectedArchive.Value)  //sync call
        }
    });


    //====================configure the grid==================
    $("#mainGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: mainGridDataSource,
        columns: Search.Grid.GenerateColumns(Search.SelectedArchive.Value),  //sync call
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        filterable: {  
            mode: "row"
        }
    });

} 


//build the columns collection  server side
Search.Grid.GenerateColumns = function (archivio) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _rootUrl + 'Repository.aspx/GetArchiveColumns',
        data: JSON.stringify({ archivio: archivio }),
        success: function(data) {
            return data.d;
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    });
}
//output (the grid columns)
{"d":[{"field":"Id","title":"Id","type":"number"},{"field":"NumeroDocumento","title":"NumeroDocumento","type":"string"},{"field":"DataDocumento","title":"DataDocumento","type":"date"},{"field":"NumeroDocumentoUsoInterno","title":"NumeroDocumentoUsoInterno","type":"string"},{"field":"NumeroOrdine","title":"NumeroOrdine","type":"string"}]}

//build the model collection server side
Search.Grid.GenerateModel = function (archivio) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _rootUrl + 'Repository.aspx/GetArchiveModel',
        data: JSON.stringify({ archivio: archivio }),
        success: function (data) {
            return data.d;
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    });
}
//output (the datasource model)
{"d":{"id":"Id","fields":{"Id":{"type":"number"},"NumeroDocumento":{"type":"string"},"DataDocumento":{"type":"date"},"NumeroDocumentoUsoInterno":{"type":"string"},"NumeroOrdine":{"type":"string"}}}}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but you might want to make your call for you grid metadata, and then upon successful retrieval, create your grid.  I think what you are seeing now is just a timing issue.

Comment: so what you are saying me is: load  the metadata  first (columns and model) and, only then, load data! is it correct?
What i'm doing is not in the correct order? is it so? help me to understand because i can't speak english well

Comment: I'll post an answer with some more detail

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your call to get the metadata and not attempt to create the grid until you successfully receive it - something along these lines:

```
// make the ajax call for metadata - don't create 
// the grid until this call is successful
$.ajax({
    url: "http...",
    // other configurations
    success: function (e) {
        // create the grid        
        createGrid(e);                        
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);        
    }
});

createGrid(metaData){

    // create the grid using the metadata

}
```

Comment: i thought that using "async: false" in the ajax calls was enough, anyway i'll try to move that loading first, and create the grid after